# CASE statement using exists?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query with example account:

```
select account_no, eventid 
from Table
where account_no = '004281200206094138'
```

Producing the following results:

[image]

I was thinking there'd be some way to write a CASE statement, perhaps also using an EXISTS, but I can't quite figure out how to do it, or if that combo is even possible. What I want to accomplish is the following (pseudocode):

`When 223 and 224 both exist for an account, show me only 224. Else show me eventid`

Comment: `CASE` **expression** not a statement. And you're looking for `MAX()`

Comment: `MAX()` may work, but not sure how I'd implement it so as to avoid always pulling 224 and not 223 when I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When 223 and 224 both exist for an account, show me only 224. Else show me eventid

```
SELECT AccountNumber, MAX(EventId) EventId
FROM YourTable
-- WHERE AccountNumber = '004281200206094138' if needed
GROUP BY AccountNumber
```

Comment: Oh I see. You're quite right, I didn't stop to consider the inherent boolean nature of this scenario. I actually think I prefer this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `CASE` just add a condition with `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select t.account_no, t.eventid 
from tablename t
where t.account_no = '004281200206094138'
  and (
    eventid <> 223
    or 
    not exists (select 1 from tablename where account_no = t.account_no and eventid = 224)
  )
```

Comment: Haven't used EXISTS much I tend to get by with IN with my normal querying, so seeing it used in this way is elegantly simple. Thank you so much!